# CIFilterGenerator failing with CIColorMap

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to create a `CIFilterGenerator` for use with a CALayer using the following code:

```
CIFilterGenerator *generator = [[CIFilterGenerator alloc] init];

CIFilter *colorFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIConstantColorGenerator"];
[colorFilter setDefaults];
[colorFilter setValue:[CIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:1.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5] forKey:kCIInputColorKey];

CIFilter *cropFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CICrop"];
[cropFilter setDefaults];
[cropFilter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:0.0 Y:0.0 Z:1.0 W:1.0] forKey:@"inputRectangle"];
[generator connectObject:colorFilter withKey:kCIOutputImageKey toObject:cropFilter withKey:kCIInputImageKey];

CIFilter *colorMap = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMap"];
[colorMap setDefaults];
[generator connectObject:cropFilter withKey:kCIOutputImageKey toObject:colorMap withKey:kCIInputGradientImageKey];

CIFilter *blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[blur setDefaults];
[blur setValue:@10.0 forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];
[generator connectObject:colorMap withKey:kCIOutputImageKey toObject:blur withKey:kCIInputImageKey];


[generator exportKey:kCIInputColorKey fromObject:colorFilter withName:nil];
[generator exportKey:kCIInputImageKey fromObject:colorMap withName:nil];

[generator exportKey:kCIOutputImageKey fromObject:blur withName:nil];
```

However, when I try to attach this to a layer, I get an exception:

```
/SourceCache/CoreImage/CoreImage-8.2.2/API/CIFilter.mm:588: CIColorMap apply:: Caught exception: CIColorMap: colorMap: nil value for argument #0 (src)
```

Which is odd, because I'm exporting the color maps input image. What's even stranger, is that if I change the exported output image to the color map, it works as expected (minus the blur of course).

Comment: Does it fail with a minimal filter chain as well? E.g. just `CIColorMap` or `CIColorMap` connected to your `colorFilter`?

Comment: Yes. It appears that if I set an image to the input image (any image, I used constant color), it works just fine. When the filter gets applied to the layer, the temp image is replaced and all is well. But as soon as you try to access the filter if it doesn't have a default input image, it throws an exception. Thinking this is a bug.